# Issues for having two "Include" in one of my page - PHP

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php require_once('php/auth.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120" >


    <!-- Start of slideshow -->

    <style type="text/css">
    .slideshow { height: auto; width: auto; margin: auto }
    .slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
    </style>
    <!-- include jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/lib.js"></script>
    <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });
    });
    </script>



    <!-- END of slideshow-->



</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFF66">

<div id="contain"> 

<!-- Master header for all the pages -->
    <?php include 'php/head.php'; ?>

    <div id="bodyDiv">

        <?php 

        // Div for the slider in jquery
        echo "<div class='slideshow'>";

        // Both of these are working when tested and included alone
        // This is where my problem lies, if I include them both, the 2nd one will not appear, the first one will only be showing its output.
            include 'php/bussvolci.php';
            include 'php/bussvolap.php';
        echo "</div>";
        ?>


    </div>


</div>

</body>


</html>
```

As commented in the code section, my problem lies with the two include that only shows 1 output, it will only output the `include 'php/bussvolci.php';` and will ignore/or does not show any output in `include 'php/bussvolap.php'`. I already tested them both individually and they both work, but when I put them in a single page where I would like to the reports in a slideshow effect only the first table is shown. Those pages both output 1 table with different datas but comes from single table. Can you guys help me with this problem.

**This is my bussvolap.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../design.css" />
</head>

<body>

<?php

function inputDate(){
                    define('TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Manila');
                    date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE);
                    return date('Y-m-d');
                }

        include 'con_test.php';

        echo "<table name='volAp' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1' rules='rows' style='font-family:Calibri; margin:0 auto 0 auto; font-size:15px; text-align:center; padding:4px;'>
                        <tr border='1'>
                            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Products&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Real Estate&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;TVR&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Auto Appraisal&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>";


// START OF Mortgage PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// Mortgage - Real Estate
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Mortgage'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Real Estate'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<tr><td>Mortgage</td> <td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Mortgage - Real Estate

// Mortgage - TVR
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Mortgage'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - TVR'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of Mortgage TVR

    echo "<td> - </td></tr>";

// End OF Mortgage PRODUCT -------------------------------------------- 


// START OF SME PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// Mortgage - Real Estate
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'SME'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Real Estate'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<tr><td>SME</td> <td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Mortgage - Real Estate

// Mortgage - TVR
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'SME'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - TVR'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of Mortgage TVR

    echo "<td> - </td></tr>";

// End OF SME PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// START OF Corpbank PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// Mortgage - Real Estate
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Corpbank'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Real Estate'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<tr><td>Corpbank</td> <td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Mortgage - Real Estate

// Mortgage - TVR
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Corpbank'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - TVR'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of Mortgage TVR

    echo "<td> - </td></tr>";

// End OF Corpbank PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// START OF Combank PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// Mortgage - Real Estate
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Combank'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Real Estate'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<tr><td>Combank</td> <td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Mortgage - Real Estate

// Mortgage - TVR
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'Combank'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - TVR'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of Mortgage TVR

    echo "<td> - </td></tr>";

// End OF Combank PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// START OF CCD PRODUCT --------------------------------------------


    echo "<tr><td>CCD</td> <td> - </td>";

    echo "<td> - </td>";

// CCD - Auto
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'CCD'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Auto'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td></tr>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of CCD - Auto


// End OF CCD PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// START OF WAF PRODUCT --------------------------------------------


    echo "<tr><td>WAF</td> <td> - </td>";

    echo "<td> - </td>";

// WAF - Auto
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'WAF'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Auto'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td></tr>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of WAF - Auto


// End OF WAF PRODUCT --------------------------------------------

// START OF PhilMay PRODUCT --------------------------------------------


    echo "<tr><td>PhilMay</td> <td> - </td>";

    echo "<td> - </td>";

// CCD - Auto
    if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                    AND `rec_prod` = 'PhilMay'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Auto'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td>%d</td></tr>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of PhilMay - Auto


// End OF PhilMay PRODUCT --------------------------------------------


// Start of Total --------------------------------------------

// Real Estate Total
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Real Estate'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<tr><td><b>Total</b></td> <td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Real Estate Total

// Appraisal - TVR Total
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - TVR'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td> %d </td>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }

// end of Appraisal - TVR Total

// Appraisal - Auto Total
        if ($result = $con->query("
        SELECT `recID` 
            FROM `samprec` 
                WHERE `recDate` = '".inputDate()."'
                        AND `rec_proc` = 'Appraisal - Auto'")) {

            /* determine number of rows result set */
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            printf("<td> %d </td></tr>", $row_cnt);

            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
// end of Appraisal - Auto Total

// End of Total --------------------------------------------

        echo "</table>";
?>


</body>

</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

the error.log shows two 2 errors

PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare inputDate() (previously declared)

PHP Notice: Constant TIMEZONE already defined

the bussvolap.php [link](http://pastebin.com/W035Uet0) .. the bussvolci.php [link](http://pastebin.com/syXvWf7V)

**Solution**

The problem was having the same function, includes of connection strings, and maybe css links on both included pages. What I did is removed the links to css, function (which is defining the same timezone and having the same function name), and remove the connection string from the 2nd `Include`

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML source, maybe you forgot to close an element somewhere?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your PHP error.log?

Comment: @Ely "where do I search for that PHP error.log?" Sorry, but you simply cannot develop PHP without first getting access to your error log. It reports all kinds of warnings, errors, notices. Some things that while don't break the program (warnings and notices) do provide VITAL information about your code. The location depends on the install, but usually it's in /var/log/apache2/error.log. If you're on Linux, as root/SU just try "locate error.log"

Comment: @Ely - you should be able to comment on your own question regardless of rep. The <50 rep cap is only commenting on others questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you also show the content of the 'bussvolap.php' and 'bussvolap.php' files..

check whether you are using 'exit' or 'die' somewhere in those files.

Comment: I searched for those keywords in my codes but didn't find any, I am using `$result->close();` to close a result set if that helps.

Comment: @Ely have you tried keeping(including) the 'php/bussvolap.php' above 'bussvolci.php' in your main php file.do both the scripts work that way.

Comment: yes, the output will be the one on the top. I also tried putting them in different `<div>` but the output is the same wherever I position the other one. Can I make another page that includes both of them in there and then `Include` that page in my main?

Comment: and why have all the answers to this question been -1 for nothing.. the person should atleast mention some reason.

Comment: @Ely you can do that too...and you can find the error.log by following instructions on [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/) page.

Comment: I have found the log and it shows 2 errors

--PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare inputDate() (previously declared----
 ----PHP Notice:  Constant TIMEZONE already defined----

Comment: these comments should be under your question, as so should this answer as a comment sigh. Update your question and put the error there, the full error including the path/filename etc

Comment: @Ely i have already suggested you an edit...just review that and accept it

Comment: @James.I dont have the minimum reputation to comment there.

Comment: @Raymond Elferink - akki and James -- Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @Ely our pleasure...what was the problem exactly..? :D

Comment: The problem was having the same function, includes of connection strings, and maybe css links on both included pages. What I did is removed the links to css, function (which is defining the same timezone and having the same function name), and remove the connection string from the 2nd `Include`

Answer (score 0):

What is inside those two included files?

If they die() the first will stop further execution of your script.

Comment: I have reached the 30k limit and can't post the code for bussvolCI.php and dont have the reputation for adding my own answer yet

Comment: @James - Sorry for asking, where do I search for that PHP error.log?

Comment: @Ely - just thati see no obvious problems in the code you posted. I would look for the error in those two files.

Comment: @RaymondElferink - this is my index [link](http://pastebin.com/s0rpF16h) .. the bussvolap.php [link](http://pastebin.com/W035Uet0) .. the bussvolci.php [link](http://pastebin.com/syXvWf7V)  thanks for the help

Comment: @Ely - your includes seem to include html tags that are already in your index. Plus they define the same functions. I think this needs major rethinking.

Comment: @RaymondElferink - Thanks for that Raymond, i commented out my link to the css for both the bussvolci.php and bussvolap.php, and also commented out the inputDate() functions in the second include. It is now showing. I only needed to input test data to check the accuracy. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ely - happy to have been of help

Comment: By the way: is it customary here to be downvoted for being helpful??

Comment: I didn't do that since I don't have the repu, Thanks for your help again. I can now move on to other problems :P

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was you had the same function repeated and PHP threw the:

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare inputDate() (previously declared)

A fatal error will halt the script (unless you have some user defined error handling etc). This is why your 2nd include was failing.

So is why you should always make use of your error.log file throughout all development.

Even warnings and notices (non-critical errors that don't halt the script) shouldn't be ignored.

The:

> PHP Notice: Constant TIMEZONE already defined

Is just a notice and while wont make your script halt, these warnings and notices that PHP *kindly* reports back to us are VERY useful. It allows us to streamline our code, correcting small niggles here and there. While some people argue can be ignored, and some even use @ to suppress these low level warnings, they should be addressed if you want a 100% clean and professional script(s).

You should always check your error log, and once you're done with a new script, or changes to a current one etc, clear your error.log (echo > error.log), then run the script in the browser, if all looks ok, check the error log (tail error.log - default last 10 lines of code in that file)

The error log helps you fix broken code, such as this one you have just resolved, but also things that while on face value might seem pointless, and wont ever break your code from running, further down the line it can break something in your web page itself.
Such as a warning that you are checking on an undeclared variable might point you to a typo in the variable name. You meant `$UserName` and not `$USerName` - it happens.

In that case, while PHP wont halt, the web page loads and you look wondering why there is no username displayed where you intended it to be!

Also such as the *notice* above "Constant TIMEZONE already defined". You need to check your constants are not duped, as without checking the error.log, one day you might change one of the constants, the later one, and wonder why your changes have no affect throughout the site!

---

In terms of your require or include, you can use require_once or include_once, to avoid issues with dupe code and functions etc, although it wont fix having the same function in two files.

To resolve that, you need to design your framework or site setup carefully, keeping in mind at all times to separate business logic from presentation where ever possible.

Then you'd have a separate file to define functions, include it once in a file that is included in all pages (such as header.php or config.php) and then you know whatever page (script file) you are working on the function is already there for you.

That said, take care not to include everything for the sake of it, if you can ensure you only include things in places they're needed then you write more efficient code!

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I have been given a small timeframe to work with this project.. therefore I am building it while also learning what I can. Thanks for the tip regarding a page that is included in every page where I want to put my functions and scripts.

Comment: np - glad it helped. Try to do the bare basics for your project, so it's complete as per requested, then any spare time add additional things to show you understand other aspects of the project.

Comment: Thanks again, now the problem I am having is regarding of inserting multiple rows from checkboxes in a loop. Would you help? Been stuck with this for 3 hours

Comment: Happy to but should be in another question really, we cannot help in comments on an answer to a different question. Also not sure why you accepted a downvoted answer which isn't really an answer :(

Comment: akki suggested the edits regarding about having same functions etc. he pointed me to php error logs, which I didn't know existed :P. Anyway, here is the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479033/inserting-checkboxes-into-different-rows)

Comment: Their answer was a brief statement at a guess. I provided a lot of info to help. nm glad you're sorted

Answer (score -1):

You should show us the contents of the two files that you are including. It is almost certainly a problem with the contents of these files.

Can you see the contents of these files when you view the source of the web page?

Comment: How do you know it's "certainly" a problem with the content of these files? And I can answer your question - no they cannot see the PHP code from viewing the source of the web page.